# WebAPI MapHttpRoute doesn't work, but AttributeRouting does

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a case where I can't get a default route to work via `Config.Routes.MapHttpRoute()`, but if I put the route as a route attribute in the controller it works fine.

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    //BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

(removed last two as they're non-WebAPI requirements (right?) same result even if I leave them in)

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public class ErrorsController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("v1/Errors/Get")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("v1/Errors/Submit")]
    public IHttpActionResult Submit()
    {
        // do stuff   
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

If I have the attribute routes in there, everything works fine.  If I don't, I get 404s.  For example, the following two report a 404 error:

`localhost:myport/v1/Errors/Get?id=5`

`localhost:myport/v1/Errors/Submit`

Yet, if I submit this:

`localhost:myport/v1/Errors`

I get the following response:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:59498/v1/Errors/'.
>
> No type was found that matches the controller named 'v1'.

Obviously my route configuration isn't kicking in, but for the life of my I can't tell why.  I even tried changing the route name to `Default` instead of `DefaultApi`, thinking that perhaps `Default` had some internal significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Normal" routing doesn't support this kind of routes with prefix "v1" in it. In a way or another this kind of rounting follows the old MVC routing, where the first part of the address must be the controller; so when you set the address `localhost:myport/v1/Errors` the system is currently looking for a controller named "*v1*".

If you want to use a route with a prefix before you have to stick with the attribute routing; that's why it works perfectly with attributes and it doesn't without.

May I suggest you to use a "global" prefix for the v1 thing? That would allow you to avoid repeating the same part of the URL over and over again on different resources. I suggest you to check [this](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/10/global-route-prefixes-with-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/) article for a couple of implementation details.

Comment: Ah ha... that makes sense.  To confirm though, this is ok for specialized routes in non-web API routing? (I've used similar constructs with prefixes as non-default routes in regular MVC).  In any case, thanks for the answer - now I know why (and have a useful link as well).